# I cannot install @ionic/cli-plugin-proxy : 1.3.0

Tags: ionic-framework, npm, npm-install, ionic4

I am trying to download ionic/cli-plugin-proxy as I am working behind a proxy server but I am getting this error:

```
npm install -g @ionic/cli-plugin-proxy
npm ERR! code E500
npm ERR! 500 Internal Server Error: @ionic/cli-plugin-proxy@latest

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\KAA1WA3\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-03-26T16_24_55_559Z-debug.log
```

What am I missing? I set env variables for proxy. I also set the proxy for npm and git globally.

```
Ionic:

   ionic (Ionic CLI) : 4.12.0


Cordova: 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)


System:

   NodeJS : v10.15.2
   npm    : 6.4.1
   OS     : Windows 10

Environment:

   HTTP_PROXY       : http://localhost:3128/
   http_proxy       : http://localhost:3128/
   HTTPS_PROXY      : http://localhost:3128/
   https_proxy      : http://localhost:3128/
   IONIC_HTTP_PROXY : http://localhost:3128/
   PROXY            : http://localhost:3128/
   proxy            : http://localhost:3128/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add your username to the proxy configuration

```
npm config set proxy http://USERNAME@PROXYIP:PORT
```

Depending on your network if you are part of a domain you will need to set it as

```
npm config set proxy http://DOMAIN%5CUSERNAME@PROXYIP:PORT
```

%5C is the encoding for the backslash \ between your domain and user name.

Also depending on your network (but unlikely) you may have to include your password, so use

```
http://DOMAIN%5CUSERNAME:PASSWORD@PROXYIP:PORT
```

Answer (score 0):

run the cmd as Administrator , locate your project and run following commands

```
npm config set proxy http://PORXYIP:PORT
npm config set https-proxy http://PORXYIP:PORT
npm set strict-ssl=false
npm install  @ionic/cli-plugin-proxy
```

Comment: unfortunately, it does not work(btw I already set the npm config proxy settings).

Comment: @KathrineHanson  if still you are stuck with same issue just try disconnect your corporate network and connect your PC to open network and install the packages . You will not get proxy problem in that case